# Determine whether number is a multiple of 5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How would I go about determining if a number is a multiple of 5?

In my app, I want one method to run if a certain number is not a multiple of 5, and another method to run if the method *is* a multiple of 5.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AnoopVaidya give him time. There is a fifteen minute window during which you *can not* accept an answer, period.

Comment: Yes, I tried to accept it right away, but couldn't. Then I had to step away from the computer for a few hours. I accepted Jonathon's answer, since his was correct and the first response.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Swift 5 UPDATE**

According to newly released language version you can determine this using [isMultiple(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/3127688-ismultiple) method

```
let num = 75
if num.isMultiple(of: 5) {
    // multiple of 5
} else {
    // not a multiple of 5
}
```

Use the [**modulus** operator](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/3601/objective-c-programming-tutorial-8-basics-of-modulus-operator/) to check the remainder of integer division.

```
if (num % 5 == 0) {
    // multiple of 5.
}
else {
    // not a multiple of 5.
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Use the modulus operator:

```
if (num % 5 == 0)
    //the number is a multiple of 5.
else
    // the number is not a multiple of 5.
```

The modulus operator returns the remainder of a division instead of the division itself, so this logic will work with any number, not just 5. i.e. `if (num % 3 == 0) //multiple of 3`

Answer (score 3):

Check by this simple logic.

Find the remainder, if it is 0, that means it is completely divisible by 5.

```
if(number % 5 == 0) {
   NSLog(@"Multiple of 5");
   //[self multipleOfFive];//your method
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Not a multiple of 5");
    //[self notMultipleOfFive];//your method
}
```

Note: **You can only check % (modulus) for integers**

for floats or doubles use :

```
double fmod(double x, double y);
float fmodf(float x, float y);
long double fmodl(long double x, long double y);
```

Comment: Because of your rude comment above.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII : Sorry sir, actually i wanted to know what happens once i read 200+ points in a day... please excuse me :(

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I was the first downvoter. Your answer was incorrect until you saw my correct answer from 7 seconds earlier.  Besides your answer contains a much of irrelevant stuff that distracts from the question at hand.

Comment: In my first post i missed ==0, while I was completing the answer.  I have mentioned few other methods and OP did not say it is integer or floating number. And inside the if-else i have commented the method so that his requirement is achieved as ` I want one method to run if a certain number is not a multiple of 5, and another method to run if the method is a multiple of 5.`

Comment: >actually i wanted to know what happens once i read 200+ points in a day. @AnoopVaidya [how reputation work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: 200 is the cap after that you wont get any points added. sometime 230 will be maximum. it happens to me everyday :(

Comment: @moderator : Now this is teasing me, someone downvoted 3 questions today, i removed 2 questions as they didn't contain any upvotes, but what about this one? Is my answer wrong, after having +6 one down vote, you can check the person who is downvoting me, and this is not serial downvotes. Every day i am getting downvotes on 3-4 answers and questions.

Comment: @vikingosegundo : Yes Sir :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163785/getting-downvotes-in-bulk-on-different-questions

Comment: So why are you making so much noise here? You are getting way enough reputation every day, why are so few down votes bothering you so much? Attention: this was a rhetoric question, I actually don't want an answer. And if you want to reach moderators, use flagging. But with your requests you won't make much friends.